# Does OrmLite support MetadataType attribute?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm learning servicestack.ormlite and I encountered this problem.

When I use this POCO, I get a Primary Key error.

This made me think that the MetadataType attribute does not have any effect and I gave the autoincrement attribute to the property "Id" in the class called User.

That way, the code worked correctly. Could the reason of that is because of using the attribute MetadataType wrong or the support of ORMLITE to MetadataType attribute..?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
}


public class UserMetadata
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MetadataType Attribute is not supported in ServiceStack's [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/).